# What does this regex match? \\b${0}.*

Tags: regex

I can't quite figure out what to make of this:
\b${0}.*
What is that supposed to match? Backspaces, or rather, lack thereof?

Comment: There are several regular expression languages. You should give more context.

Comment: I doubt the regex is even valid, as far as I know the `&` symbol (string end) may not be used with any repeat rule (neither zero repeats).

Comment: Is ${0} correct? I don't think anchors are quantifiable.

Comment: If you want to know what a regexp means, enter it at http://www.regexr.com/ and hover your mouse over the pieces.

Comment: see here http://regex101.com/r/tC2mB9

Comment: It also doesn't seem to make sense to have `{0}` repetition before `.*`. Because if there's more than 0 of the item, they'll be matched by `.*` after it.

Answer (score 0):

That to me looks like part of a shell script more than a traditional regex.

In Bash something like ${0} would be the first field in a command and symbols like * are wildcards rather than quantifiers. Now I'm not saying it makes much sense to me. But it makes more sense than as a regex.

Answer (score 0):

What does it match, you ask?

**It doesn't**

`{number}` repeats the previous item `number` times. `$` Is an anchor; it matches the location at the end of the input. Obviously, a location cannot be repeated, so any regex containing `${number_here}` is invalid.

Ignoring that part, `\b` is a *word boundary*, i.e. it matches a location that is either preceded by a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and followed by a non-word character, or vice versa. `.` matches any character except for newline characters, and `*` repeats the previous item zero or more times, as many times as possible. Therefore, `.*` matches any sequence of zero or more characters that don't include newlines.